# POST request in flask app replaces data, rather than adding it the the current data

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have created an e-commerce application using flask. A feature that I have added is the ability for customers to bookmark/favourite products. I have created the necessary relationships and nesting, in my models, serializers and SQL allowing users to bookmark multiple products. I have tested this by hard coding it in my seed file and it works.

However, I am struggling to write the logic for an "add_to_favourites" function, which I need to make it work in my front-end. My POST request replaces a previously saved bookmark rather than adding the new bookmark, creating a list of bookmarks. As a result I am only able to have one bookmark at a time. This is the function that I have written:

```
@router.route('/customers/<int:id>/products', methods=['POST'])
@secure_route
def add_favourite(id):
  existing_customer = CustomerModel.query.get(id)
  single_product = ProductModel.query.get(id)
  single_product_data = product_schema.dump(single_product)

  current_favourite = populated_customer.load({
    "products" :[single_product_data]},
    instance=existing_customer,
    partial=True
  )  

  if existing_customer.id != g.current_user.id:
    return { 'message': 'You cannot update a profile that is not yours'}, 404

  try:
    new_favourite = populated_customer.load(
      request.get_json(),
      instance=existing_customer,
      partial=True
    )
  except ValidationError as e:
    return { 'errors': e.messages, 'message': 'Something went wrong.' }

  new_favourite.save()

  return customer_schema.jsonify(new_favourite, current_favourite), 201
```

The many-many relationship between the tables is here:

```
class CustomerModel(db.Model, BaseModel):

  __tablename__ = "customers"

  username = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False, unique=True)
  password_hash = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
  products = db.relationship('ProductModel', secondary=customers_products_join, backref='customers')
```

And the join table:

```
customers_products_join = db.Table('customers_products',
  db.Column('customer_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('customers.id'), primary_key=False),
  db.Column('product_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('products.id'), primary_key=True)
)
``

Can anyone help point out where I am clearly going wrong? (Please note that this is just the newest iteration of the function that I have tried - I've tried a lot!)
```

Comment: None of the relevant code is visible here. The only relevant part is `new_favourite = populated_customer.load(...)` and `new_favourite.save()` and there is no way to know whether that is supposed to add or replace. Do you even have a one-to-many relationship in the data model to begin with?

Comment: The model uses an M-M relationship and that works fine. I've added an edit above.

Comment: What do you mean by M-M? There is an intermediate table? But isn't `instance` a foreign key linking to the customer?

Comment: Sorry, I mean many-to-many. I used a join table. Everything works as far as my relationships go to my knowledge. 

I just can't get my logic right in order to add many bookmarks. It replaces rather than adds and I'm not sure how to change that.

Comment: Instance is not the foreign key, it is pointing to the customerID that is adding the bookmark.

Comment: I think you should take a look at your primary keys in the join table.